# Include SP.JS in Custom ASPX Page

Tags: sharepoint-online, csom, aspx, sp.js

I've created a new ASPX page in the root of an O365 site collection (not in Site Pages or Pages, just in the very root folder via the All Files view in SharePoint Designer), and struggling to work out how to include the required SP.JS libraries that get loaded as standard in a Web Part Page.

I've tried a few different things, including the suggested `<Sharepoint:ScriptLink>` tags I've seen mentioned elsewhere; also tried a direct `<script>` tag to the literal file locations inside the /_layouts folder.

Neither seems to work and I'm using a verbatim copy of some JS that works fine on a web part page.

Any ideas? This seems to be one of those questions there are a ton of answers to but none seem to work for me.

Comment: have you tried with Page.RegisterStartupScript Method and ClientScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript Method??

Comment: No, how do I use those? Not familiar with that code.

Comment: pls check this example: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z9h4dk8y(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I'm not really following how that is relevant; the code example is missing any sort of reference to SP.JS. Am I missing something?

Comment: This is a poor practice. Working against the platform like this is going to cause all sorts of problems in the long run. You're better off using the structure SharePoint gives you (SitePages, etc) and building your solutions atop the platform, rather than sidestepping it.

Comment: You are right in theory but I don't see why I should be constrained by the interface Microsoft provides, especially since when they finally apply the Modern Experience to sites as well as lists it will be all change and surely introduce some new annoyances (as it always does with O365). I appreciate that it's best practice not to do this but I wasn't really asking for an opinion, just a solution as it surely must be possible.